# How can I avoid duplicates in my "mysql" database when using hibernate (JAVA)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I parse a .lst file to get data, then I use hibernate in order to add these data in a mysql database.

My file is always updated with new data but it KEEPS existing ones.

The question is how can I avoid duplicates data in my database when I parse the file a scond time.

Thanks

Comment: By adding a unique index in my database I risk to have an exception in my code, because I try to add elements that won't be accepted in my database.
I'll test it anyway and I'll tell you if it works.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table_name ('your fields') VALUES ('New values') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1=' value',field2='value',.....;

Table Structure: 
make this 2 fields (name and city )Uniqe
ex:

INSERT INTO tbl_stud(`name`,`city`)values('Divyesh','Ahmedabad') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='Divyesh',city='Ahmedabad';